# why does putting an alert within a setTimeout in a for loop break the alert?

Tags: javascript

I have an extremely simple `script` which is supposed to grab every element with and `id="d"`, then iterate through each of those elements; grabbing the value of their `data-color`.

Each time it loops through, it is supposed to change the background of the `document` to those values, then alert the value.

It would work, and grab all of the values, and output them; one after the other. However, due to the alerts being too quick for the page to actually change the `background` color, I had to put the alerts within a `setTimeout` so that the `document` could change color, wait 250 milliseconds, **THEN** alert the value. When I did this though, it would only ever get the last elements `data-color` value and alert it.

This is my **JavaScript**:

```
var selector = document.querySelectorAll("#d");

for(var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++){
    var did = selector[i].getAttribute("data-color");

    document.body.style.background = did; // set background to data-color value
    setTimeout(function(){ // wait 250 milliseconds (this is where it breaks)
        alert(did); // THEN alert the value of data-color
    }, 250);
}
```

And the **HTML**:

```
<div data-color="green" id="d"></div>
<div data-color="blue" id="d"></div>
<div data-color="red" id="d"></div>
```

Why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Ids must be unique. Also, all your timeouts will run at the same time, since they all start at the same time. Finally, `did` in your alert will always have its last value by the time the timeouts run.

Comment: @torazaburo but, it worked beforehand when I removed `setTimeout`? So it mustn't be something to do with the `id`, rather the timeout? Then shouldn't it just be repeating green?.. Apologies if it sounds a bit dumb, but I'm very new to JavaScript

Comment: it takes longer than 250ms to dismiss the alert, so I am not sure this will get the desired output - what about just logging the colour change? - oh, and the issues with `id`s will not cause this but it is another coding standard/validity issue (they are supposed to be unique; you can change them to classes instead)

Comment: @ochi ohh okay :-) I was not aware of this. I have been using `id`'s due to some elements being proceduraly generated through `PHP`, so I am unable to change the `classes`'s or `id`'s

Comment: @OlegEstekhin there may be another answer, but just because there is, it doesn't mean I understand it. Hence, the reason I created a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `id`s for `class`es - also changed the `setTimeout` for `setInterval`

I am not sure if this is the desired outcome but perhaps you can let me know more precisely what the desired outcome is :)

**See demo below**

```js
var selector = document.querySelectorAll(".d");
var i = 0; // index for traversing the array of elements

// wait 2000 milliseconds (2 secs)
var intervalHandle  = setInterval(function() {
  var did = selector[i].getAttribute("data-color");
  // set background to data-color value
  document.body.style.background = did;
  // THEN log the value of data-color
  console.log(did);
  
  // if there are more items in the array, increment index so 
  // that next interval will use the next element in array
  if (i < selector.length-1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    //otherwise, clear the interval to stop
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);
  }

},  2 * 1000); // 2 secs
```

```html
<div data-color="green" class="d"></div>
<div data-color="blue" class="d"></div>
<div data-color="red" class="d"></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou! :-) just the setTimeout however, only want it to run once

Comment: @Caelan. I now clear the interval after all element in array have been 'processed'